# how to set default language in iPhone app based on user region position

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, localizable.strings

i have a problem with localization. I need to set the default language in my app into Germany. The case is, when user region position is Germany or other country in Europe, the app has to showing the Germany text, but if user position in US, the app has to showing English text.

I already has 2 `localizable.strings` , one in `de.lproj` and one in `en.lproj`, but i dont know how to set the de.lproj as the default in Germany region. Can somebody help me?

thx

Answer (score 0):

happens automatically based on user's device language! So if you have your device in German will load auto the de.lproj but if you have it in english it will load en.lproj

Alternative solution is to have a menu option inside your app or in settings so user can select the language and load the appropriate file from your code.

Using IP or GPS to detect the country seems too expensive to me, except from that a lot of people live in countries and have different language on their device...

here is a [good tut](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) if you are interested